# Need help creating ibm watson conversation

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

If user enters i want large pizza with topings in ibm watson conversation how does pizza guy know that. Need help iam new to ibm watson

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at the information about acceptable questions. Someone else down-votes your post because it doesn't meet the guidelines. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Take a look at the following tutorials that should help to get you familiar with Watson Assistant, which is the new name for Watson Conversation. See: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/getting-started.html#gettingstarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are probably referring to one of the demo or starter code guides that follows a pizza ordering chatbot use case, like [this one](https://developer.ibm.com/code/patterns/assemble-a-pizza-ordering-chatbot-dialog/).

These demos are really just to help people get started with understanding how Conversation (renamed now to Watson Assistant) works. In practice, a middle-layer or orchestration layer would issue the request to an API or internal system that creates the order and tells the pizza man what to make. This system design is not just for ordering pizza of course, but can be implemented for any type of system where you have a chatbot and want to call out to third-party APIs, internal systems, or external processes. Here's an example architecture diagram depicting this:

[image]